# Same size font looks like a different size

Tags: css

As you can see, both of these buttons have text that's the same font-size, but appear very different in size.
[image]

With devtools open you can see that both buttons have `font-size: 16px` They are also both the same font ('Roboto').

Any idea what could be causing this discrepancy?

To clarify, I am working on recreating a website that's currently on WordPress. While I do have access to the back end on WordPress, it's handled by the theme so I can't see the actual code.

Comment: The left one opened in mobile view, while the second one is not.. You just selected the iphone6 size but dint refresh perhaps...

Comment: I don't think the left side has 16px title text. :3

Comment: Pictures are nice but we'll need to see your code. See [mcve]

Comment: I don't have code for the one on the left. I'm redoing a WordPress site by hand.

Comment: @Shubhranshu both are open in iPhone 6 view.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you mean title.

Comment: @LaraBelle the button, not the title.

Comment: Though both titles are `font-size: 60px;` and also clearly different sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to add

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

That's why it looks like small.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome! I'll accept this answer as soon as I get a chance to test it out.

Comment: I did not forget. I didn't know about the viewport. Now I do. Thanks!